# Typings for node-adal library?

Tags: node.js, adal, typescript-typings

I'm trying to use [adal-node library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs)  and looking for typescript typings for the library. typings search yielded typings for adal-angular and not sure if that could be used.

Has anyone else figured this out or is the adal dev team looking into releasing typings?

Answer (score 1):

There is no official Adal release which can be used with typings.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
npm install @types/adal
```

or this:

```
npm install adal-ts
```

adal-ts in writing entirely in typescript. adal-angular is not, and must be used with typings.